# Audio bot leaves channel when same command ran

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I've been making my first discord bot recently and I've finally gotten audio to play through the bot using the code below. However, if a person in the same channel as the bot uses the same command again, the bot stops playing its audio and leaves the channel. 
Additionally, how would I make it so that the bot is not able to switch channels before it has finished playing its audio.
(Note: the bot plays audio from urls containing mp3 files not with the YouTube plugin as I only want it to play specific things for a few private servers)
Heres the code:

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content == '!play EXAMPLE') {
        var channel = message.member.voiceChannel;

        if (!channel) 
            message.channel.sendMessage ('You need to be in a voice channel to use this command.');

        if (!channel)
             return console.error("The channel does not exist!"); 

        channel.join().then(connection => {
            const dispatcher = connection.playArbitraryInput("URL TO AUDIO FILE");
            dispatcher.on("end", end => { 
                channel.leave(); 
            });
        });          
    }
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should really format your code properly. This is hard to read, and you might find an error of your own once it's properly formatted.

Comment: Formatted, thanks to jtate.

Comment: check if client has already joined `channel`

Comment: What i *think* is going on... I cant verify it rn... Is that the bot is re-joining the channel(so nothing happens here) then "re-creating" dispatcher and overwriting the old dispatcher... firing `dispatcher.on("end")`

Comment: I looked about on Reddit and they said to use guild.voiceConnection to detect whether or not the bot is in a channel already, this would be used as a decider on whether or not the bot would run the command(s) or not; the only thing I can't figure out is where or how to fit it into the existing code

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is a method in the API to get the curent channel of the bot. However, one way to do this is to store the channel the bot is in a variable.

This simply sets a `botChannel` variable when joining a channel and unsets it when leaving it. So before you join the member channel, you can check if the channel is set.

*I split the code to make it easier to visualize (atleast it is for me)*

```
let botChannel = undefined;

const joinChannel = (channel) => {
    channel.join().then(connection => {
        botChannel = channel;
        playAudio(connection, 'AUDIO URL');
    });
}

const leaveChannel = () => {
    botChannel.leave();
    botChannel = undefined;
};

const playAudio = (connection, audioUrl) => {
    const dispatcher = connection.playArbitraryInput(audioUrl);
    dispatcher.on("end", end => {
        leaveChannel();
    });
};

client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content == '!play EXAMPLE') {
        var channel = message.member.voiceChannel;

        if (!channel) {
            message.channel.sendMessage('You need to be in a voice channel to use this command.');
            return console.error("The channel does not exist!"); 
        }

        if (!botChannel) {
            joinChannel(channel);
        }     
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that code fixes the issue. One thing however, using multiple instances/copies of the code (e.g. to be able to play many different audio files) results in the new copies having lots of parsing errors where the variables have already been declared, but removing the lines makes the code break by saying that those variables have not been defined. Is there any way to fix this? Many thanks.

Comment: @LgCas Could you explain to me what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'm trying to make a bot for a private server that is able to play a few different clips of audio from the internet with different commands (e.g. !play 1 would play the first clip, !play 2 would play the other and so on, presumably these commands would have to be used one after the other to avoid them cancelling each other out or use a queuing system or a command to just make it leave).

Comment: To achieve that you need to set the audio url as a parameter of the `joinChannel` function. You can then duplicate your if statement and pass the url there. Now this is not very clean and writing this cleanly is out of the scope of this thread.

Comment: Sorry about any confusion caused, I was in a hurry when I made the thread which was a mistake in the first place; and I did not think it through as the original code was allowing multiple clips to be played but the commands were cancelling each other out, it's the first bot I've made and didn't realise how the code would be influenced with certain changes. Would those parameters be made by using different versions of the playAudio line for each URL/stored video clip that I add to the bot (not searched like a YouTube bot, but manually added to the code to only allow pre added audio to play)

Comment: It would require some more work to achieve what you want. The best thing you can do is look at discord bots on Github and study how they implement such systems. Good luck!